# windows 10 installing oracle client 12c or 18c hanging at step1

Tags: oracle, windows-10

I am trying to install Oracle Client version 12c or 18c. I have tried both of the installers, and once I click next, it hangs and won't proceed any further. Same thing happens on both of the setup files. I have removed Antivirus and check the installers on a server and confirmed it works.

What other thing can go wrong with these things, could anyone give us ideas please?

Thank you!

Comment: My installation hung about 10 minutes, then went ahead.

Answer (score 6):

I had a look in the installation log under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Inventory\logs\installActions<CurrentDate_Time>.log`

It was stuck on the step:

> INFO: Checking whether the IP address of the localhost could be
>   determined...

After a lot of playing around with hosts files, etc. I ended up disabling EVERY network adapter visible in Windows 10. Installation went off without a hitch from that point. I re-enabled the needed adapter(s) following the Install step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had the same issue, and disabling every network alone did not work. I then run the "Network reset" under "network and internet settings" and then it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Disable IPv6 settings in your system and start a fresh install (whether it is 12c, 18c or 19c) if you find the below error as one of yours. It worked like a charm after searching a lot in this issue.

[nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  Reading from the pipe

Comment: Disabling IPV6 solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I tried disabling all of my network adapters (as suggested by N Dattler) and this did not solve my issue.  In desperation I started trying out different command-line parameters and I think I found the right one.  It worked for me both times I tested it:

```
setup.exe  -ignoreprereq -J"-Doracle.install.client.validate.clientSupportedOSCheck=false"
```

I tried removing either of those parameters, but it only worked with both in place.  Both seem innocent enough and the proof is that now I have a fully functional Oracle 12c client install.

P.S. Don't forget to open the command prompt window as Administrator (right click and select Run as Administrator).

Comment: It did not work for me. Below solution from khalidmehmoodawan worked. So i added as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the spaces in the name of directory and run it as administrator.

I was facing similar issue when directory path was long and had spaced. I cut/pasted at D:\ root and bang, the setup ran successfully.

Comment: Yep, keep directory names short and no spaces or it will not install. Thanks for the tip.